# Should I create should my own user with less privileges on a server (Digit. Ocean)?

Tags: ubuntu, security, users, privileges

I'm trying to deploy a website at Digital Ocean. I have the user `root` as the default. However, since it's `root` I believe I should create my own, normal user, shouldn't I? Nonetheless, in the documentation they don't say anything about it. Could you guys tell me whether or not I really should create my own user with less privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's always a very good idea to have an unprivileged account on the system to use when you do not need admin privileges.

On systems with X Window (e.g. KDE, GNOME) this is practically mandatory.

If you have console-only access it is recommended anyway to have it -- even if you're working all the time as admin. In fact, you should block remote ssh login as root for security reasons; ssh instead as this unprivileged user, then run `su -` to do your admin work.

Comment: how can I create an unprivileged user?

Comment: With the `useradd` or `adduser` commands.  Do `man useradd` or `man adduser` to read the manual pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you are neither God nor the Pope, you're not infallible, so prone to make mistakes.  **;-)** Therefore I would create 2 users:

1. A user that can read everything but not change anything:

   ```
   adduser NormalUserName
   ```
2. An "Admin" user that needs the `sudo` command to change anything.

   ```
   adduser AdminUserName
   adduser AdminUserName adm 
   adduser AdminUserName cdrom
   adduser AdminUserName sudo
   adduser AdminUserName dip
   adduser AdminUserName plugdev
   adduser AdminUserName lpadmin
   adduser AdminUserName sambashare
   ```

   (If any of the above gives an error like `group not found`, don't worry: I'm trying to be thorough)

Then:

1. Always log on as the "normal" user
2. do an `su - admin` if you know you're going to make just a few changes

**Only use root when you know that you're going to:**

- do extensive changes
- run an long script needing root privileges and that has been thoroughly tested.
- be needing I/O redirection,...

Additionally, I have a different prompt for the admin and root user (both those show a red prompt whereas the default prompt is a green one) to warn me I'm using the "dangerous" user...

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: how about downvoting?

Comment: @OskarK.: that's for users who have already accepted answers and reads: `Please don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**`  **>:-)**